# Rsync include folders and links but exclude files

Tags: linux, shell, rsync

I need to copy directory structure from one place to another. I need to copy only folders and exclude files.

Main problem is that i have link-folders !
[image]

when I type

```
rsync -avz -H  /tmp/test/ /tmp/copy/
```

it copy folders and links-folder properly, also it copy files

when I type

```
rsync -avz -H -f"+ */" -f"- *" /tmp/test/ /tmp/copy/
```

it include all folders, exclude files, but it also exclude link-folders.

when I type

```
rsync -avz -H -f"+ */" -f"- *.txt" /tmp/test/ /tmp/copy/
```

it create folders and link folders properly but exclude o
nly txt files

when I type

```
rsync -vzrptgoD -L -H -f"+ */" -f"- *" /tmp/test/ /tmp/copy/
```

it exclude files but converts link-folders in real folder,just concatenate paths.

There are many types of file and i cant just add them like -f"- *.txt"

What should i do? can i add link-folder syntax in -f"+ */"  ?

If not is there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly in `rsync`, since as you've noticed its filter rules only differentiate directories from "everything else".

However, you can construct a `find` command to pick the items you want (`l` for symbolic links, `d` for directories), and then pass that list to `rsync` for copying

```
find src/ \( -type l -o -type d \) -printf "%P\0" |
    rsync --files-from - --from0 -av src/ dst/
```

Scenario

```
mkdir /tmp/608951
cd /tmp/608951
mkdir -p src/{test1,test2} dst; ln -s test1 test/link
```

Demonstration, copying directories and symbolic links from `src` to `dst`

```
find src/ \( -type l -o -type d \) -printf "%P\0" | rsync --files-from - --from0 -av src/ dst/
```

Output

```
building file list ... done
link -> test1
test1/
test2/

sent 134 bytes  received 25 bytes  318.00 bytes/sec
total size is 5  speedup is 0.03
```

Evidence, using `ls -R src dst`, showing that `dst` contains only directories and the symbolic link, whereas `src` also contains files

```
dst:
link  test1  test2

dst/test1:

dst/test2:

src:
link  test1  test2

src/test1:
file1

src/test2:
file2
```

If you don't have GNU `find`, change its `-printf "%P\n"` to plain `-print` and also remove `--from0` from `rsync`. The downside is that you won't be able to copy files whose names contain strange characters such as newline.